# UWP RichEditBox equivalent of GetCharIndexFromPosition

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, richeditbox

It seems like the GetCharIndexFromPosition is missing in UWP's richeditbox. I want to display a tooltip when a certain range is hovered over in a RichEditBox. Is this possible with UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, we can use [GetRangeFromPoint(Point, PointOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument#Windows_UI_Text_ITextDocument_GetRangeFromPoint_Windows_Foundation_Point_Windows_UI_Text_PointOptions_) method as the equivalent of `GetCharIndexFromPosition`. This method retrieves the degenerate (empty) text range at, or nearest to, a particular point on the screen. It returns a [ITextRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextrange) object and the [StartPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextrange#Windows_UI_Text_ITextRange_StartPosition) property of `ITextRange` is similar to the character index returned by `GetCharIndexFromPosition` method.

The following is a simple sample:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <RichEditBox x:Name="editor" />
</Grid>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    editor.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, @"This is a text for testing.");
    editor.AddHandler(PointerMovedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(editor_PointerMoved), true);
}

private void editor_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(editor).Position;

    var range = editor.Document.GetRangeFromPoint(position, Windows.UI.Text.PointOptions.ClientCoordinates);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(range.StartPosition);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay, hey that works for me! Thanks so much and sorry for the delay in response!